# How can I get Soviet era arrest documents?

Tags: russia, 1930s

I saw many people having arrest and interrogation transcripts of people arrested in the 1930s in the Soviet Union.

Where can I get such documents? Are they online?

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  Would you be able to edit your question to add some genealogical context to it, please? Are you perhaps hoping to locate transcripts that relate to the arrest of one of your ancestors?  If so, a name, location and date of birth would undoubtedly be helpful.  However, please take care not to name or provide any identifying details about anyone born less than 100 years ago (see our [Help](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)).

Comment: @PolyGeo Yes. It's interesting to know what he did (or was accused of doing)